# PHP Request URI changes from echo to MySQL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to track the page URL in Wordpress using the code below. When I echo the code out, it shows fine. When I try to save it to MySQL, its showing a completely different URL.

`$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];`

`echo $pageURL;` shows **mysite.com/foo/bar**

Adding to MySQL via `update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_active_url', $pageURL);`

The wp_usermeta.last_active_url field shows **mysite.com/fontawesome/css/bootstrap.min.css**

Any tips on why the variable is changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It's a different request

if the following shows `mysite.com/foo/bar`

```
echo $pageUrl;
```

And the db data says `mysite.com/fontawesome/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Then the request that *last* updated the db is not the request you are debugging.

### The page is requesting a missing css file

Most likely what is happening is:

- Request for `/foo/bar`
- Write 'last_active_url' as `/foo/bar`
- Html rendered
- request for `/fontawesome/css/bootstrap.min.css` - file doesn't exist.
- Write 'last_active_url' as `/fontawesome/css/bootstrap.min.css`

I.e. there is no change with the variable that in the single request - it's immediately overwritten by the *next* request which is an asset the resultant html requests.

Comment: The request that updates the DB is 1 line after the `echo`, and that field for the DB is a custom one I just made up.

Comment: simply open `mysite.com/fontawesome/css/bootstrap.min.css` and look at the contents - it's either a dynamically served css file or a 4oh4.

Comment: You could be onto something since it is 404ing.